# CSS -Using percentages for widths and ems for heights

Tags: css

I have read a few places that its best to use percentages for width values and ems for heights.

Can anyone confirm this is good or not and provide any examples of sites that use this sort of layout?

Comment: But you cant really get flexible layouts using pixels can you?

Comment: There is no 'best' option. It's entirely dependent on what you are trying to accomplish. This question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: Well it's true it really depends what you're trying to build. Flexible layouts are not always the best idea, though. If Facebook used percentages for their widths, just imagine how it would look on mobile phones (excluding their mobile website).

Answer (score 2):

Using percentages and ems are good for accessibility, in that your design should scale as the customer changes magnification. Not always true, but I do try to use computed values whenever I can.

ems are from print usage, where 1 em is [the width or height of a capital letter "M"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29). I find ems useful for defining line-spacing within paragraphs, and spacing between text elements. I use percentages for laying out elements within containers.